# Software to help automate clipping/printing web page?

Tags: printing, webpage

I'm a programmer who likes to find a lot of cool technical articles / blogs on the web, but only read them on printed papers.

While a lot of websites provide the "Print Article" link that nicely formats the web page, quite a few do not provide it (Stackoverflow doesn't even have one!)

So a lot of times, what I have to do is manually highlight of the main article, and copy/paste to Word.

Sometimes I just print directly to a PDF, and then print from that.

Anyway, is there a nice software that can integrate into Firefox that can nicely format the webpage so that it's printer-friendly?

I have tried using Evernote, where it stores the entire webpage to my note, and then I can hit print from there. However, Evernote does a poor job of formatting such that all text are displayed.

Basically this question is for those who are like me: like to read a lot, like to print out a lot of web article stuff, **and** have found **the** tool they can reliably use to print the page out (instead of the usual highlight/copy/paste to word method I've been using)

Oh just want to mention: i like to print out my pages like this: 2 pages per sheet, dual-sided.

Comment: I liked your question except for the desire to print-on-paper...

Answer (score 3):

Firefox [FireShot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5648) addon.

[image]

> FireShot is a Firefox extension that creates screenshots of web pages (entirely or just visible part).
>
> Unlike other extensions, this plugin provides a set of editing and annotation tools, which let users quickly modify web captures and insert text annotations and graphical annotations. Such functionality will be especially useful for web designers, testers and content reviewers.
>
> The captures can be:
>   - uploaded to FREE public screenshot hosting
>   - saved to disk (PNG, GIF, JPEG, BMP)
>   - printed
>   - copied to clipboard
>   - e-mailed
>   - sent to configurable external editor for further processing.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Print Friendly](http://www.printfriendly.com/) and the [Printliminator](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ThePrintliminator/), I've come to prefer the Printliminator.  Don't know if they do 2-page/sheet, dual-sided. But as they both work with the browser the normal print options should be able to handle it.

**EDIT**:
I usually send the output of the Printliminator to CutePDF to save a copy then print it when i actually want to read it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a firefox addon called [**PDF Download**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/636).
Besides the **FireShot** addon, this might be sometimes quicker.
It does have its limits, but its has this excellent feature,

> Convert Web pages to PDF.
>   Convert any (unsecured) Web pages to great looking PDF files,
>   and then save, share, print or archive them.

There is a [paid version with more features](http://www.pdfdownload.org/).

Comment: i will definitely check this out. thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

**PrintWhatYouLike** lets you print the good parts of any web page while skipping ads and other junk.

Features:

- Enter a URL
- Edit The Page
- Print It

http://www.printwhatyoulike.com/